# Ripple XRP Ledger - Cant get transaction validated (Testnet)

Tags: java, ripple, xrp, rippled

Im using  testnet to validate my transaction, transaction :

**{"transaction":"ECAB482EB34177FA1B1E6C724F038C42308004B1F307A169FAEA88C825E11642","command":"tx","id":0}**

Response :

**{id=0, status='success', errorMessage='null', result=TxResult{validated=false}}**

Im using websocket , method 'tx' to check. What is the best course of action to figure out problem, is there a way to see reason this is not validated on some of the testnet validators?

Im connected to **wss://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51233**  ,address i use is **rKHDh61BpcojAoiATgJgDaVwdSJ64fGNwF**. Can someone help?

Fee is at **1 000 000 drops**. This is the transaction blob  `1200002200000000240000000061D4838D7EA4C680000000000000000000000000005553440000000000C882FD6AB9862C4F90E57E1BA15C248CABAD5BF96840000000000F42407321033BF063167F21FF6C01045B4E2F03F519879B552D2611F0E885E01F08C88D15247446304402202E90609AAFBF4C105408CFF2377D48085879BEE3C7DE57AF125F73926284362A022002D7A487F5929F9A3E1050FC2B5D6AE1DD5384647AD1ABF6D322765F0ABE0A498114C882FD6AB9862C4F90E57E1BA15C248CABAD5BF983148DC6B336C7D3BE007297DB086B1D3483DEA24C2A`

Is my transaction fualty ? Then why was it corrently submited to the network ? Seems like its valid, bud why its not validated and hence finalized in ledger?

> Note : responses use my internal model to represent some
>   properties, hence thats why names might be slightly different and some properties ommited.

Result from 'submit' call :

```
Result :SubmitResult{engineResult='tefPAST_SEQ', engineResultCode=-190, engineResultMessage='This sequence number has already passed.', txBlob='1200002200000000240000000061D4838D7EA4C680000000000000000000000000005553440000000000C882FD6AB9862C4F90E57E1BA15C248CABAD5BF96840000000000F42407321033BF063167F21FF6C01045B4E2F03F519879B552D2611F0E885E01F08C88D15247446304402202E90609AAFBF4C105408CFF2377D48085879BEE3C7DE57AF125F73926284362A022002D7A487F5929F9A3E1050FC2B5D6AE1DD5384647AD1ABF6D322765F0ABE0A498114C882FD6AB9862C4F90E57E1BA15C248CABAD5BF983148DC6B336C7D3BE007297DB086B1D3483DEA24C2A', txJson=TxJson{transactionType='Payment', account='rKHDh61BpcojAoiATgJgDaVwdSJ64fGNwF', destination='rDveJyEotoUp9jCD1Ghi2ktEBnhHiA6RBB', amount=Amount{currency='USD', value=1, issuer='rKHDh61BpcojAoiATgJgDaVwdSJ64fGNwF'}, fee='1000000', flags=0, sequence=0, signingPubKey='033BF063167F21FF6C01045B4E2F03F519879B552D2611F0E885E01F08C88D1524', txnSignature='304402202E90609AAFBF4C105408CFF2377D48085879BEE3C7DE57AF125F73926284362A022002D7A487F5929F9A3E1050FC2B5D6AE1DD5384647AD1ABF6D322765F0ABE0A49', hash='ECAB482EB34177FA1B1E6C724F038C42308004B1F307A169FAEA88C825E11642'}}
```

I submited it few times , so 'tefPAST_SEQ' is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `transaction` object has `sequence` field in it.
According to [THIS](https://developers.ripple.com/sign.html#auto-fillable-fields) your `sequence` can be auto-filled. It can be set manually in case you'd want to submit multiple `transactions` at once by incrementing them manually.
This gives you control over the order of the `transactions` to be executed in certain order.
If that doesn't matter you can just go without setting the `sequence`.

In your case your account looks like this (using [account_info](https://developers.ripple.com/account_info.html)):

```
{
"result": {
    "account_data": {
        "Account": "rKHDh61BpcojAoiATgJgDaVwdSJ64fGNwF",
        "Balance": "10000000000",
        "Flags": 0,
        "LedgerEntryType": "AccountRoot",
        "OwnerCount": 0,
        "PreviousTxnID": "12CA4E5AAF4198155FF3F16E53D35353B051F4AB5E01749833202339B48D187A",
        "PreviousTxnLgrSeq": 11450559,
        "Sequence": 1,
        "index": "169B6BA91A54B2EC86EFB618995A59E76F07853BB88AF231776118339FFD7268"
    },
    "ledger_hash": "449E3420C6B1C6959FA794066264432EF4E98543B0C6582B00D6CD28DE33B8F8",
    "ledger_index": 11523855,
    "status": "success",
    "validated": true
}
```

See the `result.account_data.Sequence` being `1`?
The reason you're seeing `This sequence number has already passed` is you've set `sequence=0` in your `transaction`. (provided by `Result from 'submit' call :`)

On a side note, I see you've set `currency='USD'` which means you have to open a `trust line` first. your account currently has `0` [account_lines](https://developers.ripple.com/account_lines.html)

Either way, good luck using XRP ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer :) so i ommit sequence, since i dont really need it, and regarding trust line, can I avoid creation of it when I just want to send XRP? Next error i encounter is 'Cannot build XRP to XRP paths.', when providing only 'Amount':<number>. Do i need to have trustline even when i want to send XRP ?

Comment: @TomasBisciak When sending XRP you just replace the whole `amount` element with the `drop` value. e.g: `"amount": "12000000"` for sending 12XRP.  
This is because XRP doesn't require a `trust line` since it's the native currency